# How to get exactly height of UILabel with line space?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm writing a expandable tableView header, I need to set the height of header accurately in tableView delegate method. I'm now using the following method to calculate the height of my header(a multi-line label):

```
CGRect calcuRect = [headerText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(myLabelWitdh, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:myLabelFont} context:nil];
CGFloat headerHeight = calcuRect.size.height;
```

However, I've found that the height calculated out is just about the text without include line space.
So how can I get the line space height of the label? or how to get accurate height of UILabel with line space?

Comment: Anyone understand me? How to get value = wordsTotalHeight+(lineNum-1)*lineSpace. this method returns the wordsTotalHeight, but how to get the value of lineSpace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the exact height of UILabel with exactly passing the same font size and type and doing some calculations.
Here I used a UILabel with Helvetica font with font size 16.

**Objective C**

```
- (CGFloat)requiredHeight:(NSString*)labelText{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.font = font;
    label.text = labelText;
    [label sizeToFit];
    return label.frame.size.height;

}
```

**Output**

```
CGFloat size = [self requiredHeight:@"iOS Rocks"];
NSLog(@"%f",size);

size = [self requiredHeight:@"iOS Rocks\n"];
NSLog(@"%f",size);
```

**Console Output**

```
2016-04-10 01:37:46.812 testPro[6093:327503] 18.500000
2016-04-10 01:37:46.814 testPro[6093:327503] 37.000000
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
func requiredHeight(labelText:String) -> CGFloat {

    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = labelText
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height

}
```

**Edit
Swift 3.0**

```
func requiredHeight(labelText:String) -> CGFloat {

    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: .max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = labelText
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rajan Maheshwari answer I wrote this function in Swift 3.0 for a generic label with the optional line height. Hope it helps.

```
func heightForLabel(_ text: String, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat, lineSpacing: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    if lineSpacing > 0.0 {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        style.alignment = .center
        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style])
    } else {
        label.text = text
    }
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the label frame.  Try: [label sizeToFit];

Comment: not about sizeToFit, I just want to know the exactly height of the multi-label

Answer (score 0):

Use below methods for same.

```
- (CGFloat)heightForWidth:(CGFloat)width usingFont:(UIFont *)font withText:(NSString *)aStrText
{
    CGSize labelSize = (CGSize){width, FLT_MAX};
    CGRect rect = [aStrText boundingRectWithSize:labelSize
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font}
                                         context:nil];
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: the problem is, this method only return height of the words, not including the line space, if the label has multiple lines, this height will be smaller than the actual height.

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
          super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
          sizeToFit()

        }
       func sizeToFit(){
            let header = customHeaderView
            let height = header.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height;
            var headerFrame = header.frame

            headerFrame.size.height = height
            header.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = header;



    }
Hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I want to create an expandable section header in my table view, however in the delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

this method must return the exactly height of my label header, I use the following method to calculate the height, however the height do not include line space but only words height;

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context;
```

Since know more about sizeToFit, here is a feasible answer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self tableViewInit];
    [self headerInit];
}

- (void)tableViewInit {
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)headerInit {
    CGRect originSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MIN);
    self.header = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:originSize];
    self.header.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    self.header.text = self.headerStr;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.showAll) {
        self.header.numberOfLines = 0;
        [self.header sizeToFit];
    } else {
        self.header.numberOfLines = 2;
        [self.header sizeToFit];
    }
    return self.header.bounds.size.height;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.header;
}
```